# How much should I charge for iOS Application?

Tags: contracts, price

Since this is my first time developing iOS application for client, so I don't know how much should I charge from them. And how long should I give them a free maintenance? (Salary Rate as iOS App Programmer in Cambodia 500$-$1000+)
Here's a features of the app:

+Client site application

-Support all iOS Devices

-Show all products of the shop

-Show location with map direction between current location and each store

-User Login and Registration for online ordering + SMS Verification ($0.013/sms)

-Online ordering:

- Select the topping of each product (drinking), size, sugar level....
- Add to Cart
- Checkout
- After done, admin will receive real time message that new order has been added.

+Admin site application(iOS)

-Add,edit,delete information of everything in the app.

-Receive real time notification and message from client for every new ordering

-Pushing notification to users

And they give me 1.5 month for developing and 0.5 months for testing.

I hope I can get any advice from you guys. I do appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly congrats on the project. In terms of quoting a figure, there is the reality that you will be doing more than just the app if it gets adopted by the company so the opportunity could also be in the long term (updates, admin, trouble shooting, new versions). It also depends if they are providing you with the marketing & artworks, that tends to be an opportunity or a pitfall depending on how you manage expectations.

I would say estimate how many hours you think you will need to finish the project, add 30% time and then put your hour rate. That would be an ideal starting point, from there you can build in the longer term opportunities like documentation and user manuals, support, updates etc. If the app gets used, you will get a call :p

Hope I haven't complicated it ;)

Comment: I do appreciate your answer and thanks :) 
I will think about it ^^